# CS0120 Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "TextBox.Text" требуется ссылка на объект

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю калькулятор WPF. Создал textbox и когда делаю чтобы при нажатии на цифровые кнопки, в TextBox’e появлялась соответствующая цифра выдает ошибку "Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "TextBox.Text" требуется ссылка на объект."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Калькулятор
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox.Text += "0";
        }
```

Comment: Какое имя у вашего тектбокса? Вот это имя и нужно использовать в коде. А `TextBox` - это название _класса_.

Comment: У вас нет поля или переменной TextBox, поэтому он думает что это попытка вызвать статическое свойство *класса* TextBox (а оно там нестатическое). Грубо говоря, вы говорите ему "сделай  такой текст у текстбокса", а он спрашивает "какого именно текстбокса?"

Comment: Alexander Petrov, trollingchar - Спасибо , все получилось